# Why can't I find the value I'm looking for

Tags: python

Basically, I want to find how many S's and W's are in a data I'm reading in Python. Am I doing it correctly or not, because when I run the program it say there are 0 s's and w's found.. which isn't true.

This is what I've done..

```
def input_function():
    my_file = open("TheData.txt", "r")

    Data = []

    for each_line in my_file:
        Data.append(each_line.split())
        print (Data)
    return Data


def Number_Of_S(Data):
    CountS= 0
    for x in range(len(Data)):
        if Data[x] == ("S"):
            CountS = CountS + 1
    print ("There are " + str(CountS) + " S's")
    return CountS


def Number_Of_W(Data):
    CountW= 0
    for x in range(len(Data)):
        if Data[x] == ("W"):
            CountW = CountW + 1
    print ("There are " + str(CountW) + " W's")

    return CountW

#Main program
Data = input_function()
Number_Of_W = Number_Of_W(Data)
Number_Of_S = Number_Of_S(Data)
```

Comment: Why don't you use built-in [`list.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method?

Comment: Your methods work fine for me. What does your `'TheData.txt'` file look like?

Answer (score 0):

What about reading the whole file into a string, then counting the characters in the string using in built functions?

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()

sCount = content.count('S')
wCount = content.count('W')

print ("There are " + str(sCount) + " S's")
print ("There are " + str(wCount) + " S's")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your count functions work just fine:

```
>>> def Number_Of_S(Data):
    CountS= 0
    for x in range(len(Data)):
        if Data[x] == ("S"):
            CountS = CountS + 1
    print ("There are " + str(CountS) + " S's")
    return CountS

>>> 
>>> Number_Of_S('HASSAH')
There are 2 S's
2
```

The problem is with your `input_function()`, which creates a list of lists (first each line is split into a list, and then those lists are appended to the `Data` list). It should simply be a list of lines, or optionally you should use three nested `for` loops in your `Number_Of_S` to loop through the words:

```
for line in Data:  # Line is a list of words
    for word in line:  # Word is a string
        for character in word:
            if character == 'S':
                CountS += 1  # Increment by one
```

---

Some other improvements, completely unrelated to your issue. Your coding style is rather unpythonic. I don't know where you learned it from, but I'd recommend you try to adjust to the "general" recommendations, such as `snake_case_variable_and_function_names` instead of `Capitalized_Names`.

Also, don't use `range()` with `for` loop unless there's no other way. In Python, you can loop directly through a list using `for element in my_list:`. With these changes in mind, this is how I think your functions should look like:

```
def number_of_s(data):
    count_s = 0
    for char in data:
        if char == 'S':
            count_s += 1  # Short for count_s = count_s + 1
    return count_s
```

And it's highly recommended to do the printing outside of the function:

```
>>> my_data = 'HASSAH'
>>> count_s = number_of_s(my_data)
>>> print("There are " + str(count_s) + " S's")
```

And instead of having multiple functions for each letter, why not use one with two arguments:

```
def number_of_characters(string, character):
    count = 0
    for char in string:
        if char == character:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Finally, I believe this is just a practice program and thus this is fine, but if you'll ever use this in a real program, you should use `list.count()` and `str.count()` instead:

```
>>> my_data = 'HASSAH'
>>> count_s = my_data.count('S')
>>> print("There are " + str(count_s) + " S's")
```

And even more finally, you should just read the whole file at once and count the characters in it:

```
with open('TheData.txt') as infile:
    text = infile.read()
print("There are " + str(text.count('S')) + " S's")
```

Answer (score -1):

You just create the wrong array. Your list was e.g.

```
['Wossd', 'sds', 'dsd', 's', 'd']
['Ssd', 'sds', 'dsd', 's', 'd']
['sdsdsd']
```

but for your counting functions it should be

```
['W', 'o', 's', 's', 'd', ' ', 's', 'd', 's', ' ', 'd', 's', 'd', ' ', 's', ' ', 'd']
['S', 's', 'd', ' ', 's', 'd', 's', ' ', 'd', 's', 'd', ' ', 's', ' ', 'd']
['s', 'd', 's', 'd', 's', 'd']
```

Modify your input function to

```
def input_function():
    my_file = open("TheData.txt", "r")

    Data = []

    for each_line in my_file:
        Data = Data + list(each_line.strip())
    return Data
```

so the output is

```
There are 1 W's
There are 1 S's
```

then rest of the code works, but there are a lot of simpler solutions